# Is_valid fails for Modelform

Tags: python, django, validation, django-forms

So I am trying to write my first "serious" web application Python/Django.  So far, so good, most of the time loving it, even though I still stumble in very silly problems, so please bear with me.

I trying to write a routine that edits a certain Model.  I built a ModelForm and a simple corresponding view.  The form gathers the data and displays it correctly, but I submit any changes, it fails validation on a `IntegerField` that had some `choices` associated to it.  It's silly, but I am stuck.

My MODEL (relevant parts):

```
class Fretes(models.Model):

    MOD_FRETE = (
        ('0', 'POR CONTA DO EMITENTE'),
        ('1', 'POR CONTA DO DESTINATARIO'),
    )

    frete_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    remetente_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    destinatario_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    endereco_remetente_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    endereco_destinatario_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    frete_por_conta = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, choices=MOD_FRETE)
    criado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modificado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    valor_frete = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
```

My FORM (relevant parts):

```
class FretesForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Fretes
        fields = ['valor_frete','frete_por_conta','apolice']
```

My VIEW (relevant parts):

```
def mudaFrete(request, id):

    frete = get_object_or_404(Fretes, pk=id)
    if request.POST:
        frete = FretesForm(request.POST, prefix='f1', instance=frete)
        if frete.is_valid():
            frete_salvo = frete.save()
            msg_erro = "FORM SALVO!"
        else:
            msg_erro = "ERRO AO TENTAR SALVAR FORM!"
        return render(request,"templates/mudafrete.html", 
                {'frete' : frete,
                 'msg_erro' : msg_erro })
    else:
        fFrete = FretesForm(prefix="f1", instance=frete)

        return render(request,"template/mudafrete.html",
                {'frete' : fFrete})
```

As I said, this code loads the data OK, but if I try to change any field, it fails validation telling me the value from "frete_por_conta" is not valid (It returns **"Make a valid choice. 0 (or any other VALID value) is not one of the available choices"** - translated freely from Portuguese)

As I understand it, it shouldn't fail any validation, since it picks the options from `choices` in the Model, but I am clearly missing something...

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an `IntegerField`, the choices should be integers, not strings.

```
MOD_FRETE = (
    (0, 'POR CONTA DO EMITENTE'),
    (1, 'POR CONTA DO DESTINATARIO'),
)
```

Comment: OUCH!!!  Pardon my **very** silly mistake.  Can only justify it with 2 reasons: (1) **bad** habits inherited from PHP and (2) one gets too tired after looking at the same code over and over and over!